# Django: ManyToMany association name not defined

Tags: python, django

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from userprofiles.models import UserProfile
# Create your models here.

import os

class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    in_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    have_images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ImageInGallery (models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)


line 22, in Image     in_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
NameError: name 'Gallery' is not defined
```

I want to have manytomany relation for Image and Gallery and class ImageInGallery to store the Image~Gallery relation sets.

also, I want images belonging to a certain gallery accessible from a gallery and vice versa, so I put both `models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)` and `models.ManyToManyField(Image)` in both classes

whats the reason of the error:

```
line 22, in Image     in_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
NameError: name 'Gallery' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the `Gallery` model above `Image`

**Ex:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from userprofiles.models import UserProfile
# Create your models here.

import os

class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    have_images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    in_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class ImageInGallery (models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
```

Comment: it does not work, because `have_images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)` will cause the same problem `NameError: name 'Image' is not defined`

Comment: Looks like you will need to change the model structure a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated relationship between `Image` and `Gallery`.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    in_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    have_images = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
```

You only need to define one of those fields and then you can use it like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) describe it.

If you remove the field `Gallery.have_images` then you can have:

```
# list all galleries a image is part of
image_instance.in_gallery.all()

# list all images from a gallery
gallery_instance.image_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your structure the way you want, and put the model name inside quote
Like:

```
have_images = models.ManyToManyField("Image")
```

if the models is in another app, use the name of the app
Ex.

```
have_images = models.ManyToManyField("app_name.Image")
```